# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool desktop and tablet apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (i.stack.imgur.com)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://meta.superuser.com/ads/display/9012).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11127/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 19):

[image: Git – fast and easy branching lets you experiment freely]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Q&A site for people seeking specific software recommendations]

Comment: I still like this one from last time. [source](http://meta.superuser.com/a/8079/116196) - it's not mine!

Answer (score 14):

[image: Make a Hardware Recommendation at Hardware Recs SE!]

Comment: Why is this so big?

Comment: @Excellll The ad is double in size but then this means that retina screens and devices will be able to displays it nicely :) It doesn't break anything, I promise :D

Answer (score 7):

[image: Git — keep working without worrying about downtime]

Comment: Probably better suited to the Stack Overflow Community Promotion Ads rather than Super User.

Comment: I've cross-posted these on [meta.programmers.se].

Comment: Stack Overflow Community Promotion Ads are special, only ads to recruit people into open source projects are accepted.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I've seen ads for other sites in the Network & Careers on Stack Overflow before.

Comment: @cybermonkey: The Careers ads are just ads that StackExchange posts to make money, they are not part of the Community Promotion Ads. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015 "*It must be an advertisement soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code.*"

Answer (score 3):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: The gray image border seems to be partially missing towards the bottom. Did you miss something while designing this?

Answer (score 2):

[image: First job? We can help!]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Fedora Workstation: This is the Linux workstation you've been waiting for.]

Answer (score 1):

[image: CmisSync: Dropbox-like desktop synchronization for Alfresco, SharePoint, FileNet, and any CMIS-compatible document management server]

Comment: Disclaimer: I have developed it, as open source (GNU-GPL license).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/90327.png))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

[image: Help build a 3D graphics knowledge base here on Stack Exchange!]

Comment: Help create a 3D graphics community here on stack exchange!